# NSTableView hangs when scrolled down in fullscreen mode

Tags: swift, nstableview, appkit

I've got a programmatically created/populated (view-based) NSTableView with 37 columns and around 119500 rows. This performs well enough - I can make the window as big as I like and still scroll around smoothly. However, when I've scrolled down (say halfway) and go into fullscreen mode, my app hangs (seemingly forever). Memory usage keeps climbing, I've seen it get upwards of 80GB. I *can* go into fullscreen mode when I'm scrolled all the way to the top, however once I'm in fullscreen mode the further I scroll down, the more lag I experience until my app beachballs.

I'm not particularly familiar with Instruments but I did a Time Profiler:

[image]

Where 'Weight' drops from 82.5% to 46.8% and follow the other path (with weight 35.7%, not in picture) is where I find another `[NSView _commonAwake]` and then `[NSNotificationCenter addObserverForName: object:queue:usingBlock:]`.

Not sure it's important, but I haven't subclassed the NSTableCellView, though their contents (standard NSTextField) are editable. I haven't noticed a difference in behaviour when toggling editable 'off'.

What is going on here? And why does my table work fine when not in fullscreen mode (but close to the same dimensions), but does not work when either transitioning to, or in fullscreen mode? Why would fullscreen work when scrolled all the way to the top, but the further I go down, the slower it becomes until it hangs, which it doesn't do when not fullscreen?

Edit 1:
In case it helps, my `tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` function is as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    
    let identifier = tableColumn!.identifier
    let viewIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier =
    (identifier == .indexTableColumnItem) ? .indexTableColumnItem : .stringTableColumnItem
    
    guard let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: viewIdentifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView
    else {
        return nil
    }
    
    // force unwrap so they don't silently fail
    let textField = cellView.textField!
    textField.target = self
    
    if identifier == .indexTableColumnItem {
        textField.font = .monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .regular)
        textField.textColor = .secondaryLabelColor
        textField.stringValue = String(row + 1)
    }
    else {
        let column: Int = tableView.column(withIdentifier: identifier)
        
        textField.stringValue = self.model[column: column - 1, row: row] ?? ""
        textField.isEditable = true
        textField.action = #selector(self.onTyping(_:))
    }
    
    return cellView
}
```

I have tried changing the contents of this to simply `return nil`, however that didn't improve the responsiveness when fullscreen.

Comment: Do you know which notification these cells are observing?

Comment: I don't - as far as I'm aware they're just regular NSTableCellView's that come with an NSTableView that I've placed in my storyboard (apart from having set them to be editable)

Comment: Hmmm interesting. And you’re reusing your cells, right?

Comment: I am, I will edit my question with my `func tableView(_:viewFor:row:)` function

Comment: That seems about right. How complex is the nib/storyboard for these cells?

Comment: All cells from the top to the last visible row are redrawn. It takes a while.

Comment: @Willeke but why does that result in a minutes long stall (and ultimately run out of memory) in fullscreen, but not in 'windowed' mode?

Comment: @Alexander I can provide a screenshot tomorrow if you like - but it's not complicated. Just a textview that shows a string value..!

Comment: In windowed mode only the visible cells are drawn (and some nearly visible cells). The cell views are reused.

Comment: Experiment: switch on "Transparent Title Bar" of the window.

Comment: Hah turning on "Transparent Title Bar" completely resolved the issue. Mostly out of curiosity, how come? Downside of this is it seems like tabs are disabled when "Transparent Title Bar" is turned on, is there any way to bring them back?

Comment: The calculation of the visible rows depends on "Transparent Title Bar" and "Full Size Conten View" (and maybe other settings). Maybe there's a combination of settings without the bug with tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up setting 'Full Size Content View' in my Window (through storyboard)